# What is the output of this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT '(Current Week)'
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -7, GetDate()), default), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -14, GetDate()), default), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -21, GetDate()), default), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -28, GetDate()), default), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -35, GetDate()), default), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, dbo.firstOfWeek(DateAdd(dd, -42, GetDate()), default), 101)
order by 1
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Without any context, [it gives a few errors](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10460), which is to be expected.

Comment: You guys are much too quick to pounce on a question and close it. At least give the OP a chance to clarify what he's trying to achieve before you shut things down. Give a warning shot over the bow, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
SELECT '(Current Week)'
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -7, GetDate()), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -14, GetDate()), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -21, GetDate()), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -28, GetDate()), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -35, GetDate()), 101)
UNION SELECT Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -42, GetDate()), 101)
order by 1

(Current Week)
01/23/2013
01/30/2013
02/06/2013
02/13/2013
02/20/2013
02/27/2013
```